# Copy values across tables where two columns are equal

Tags: mysql

I'm using MySQL and have two tables. Here are there descriptions and the first 3 rows from each:

mysql> describe table_1;

```
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

| Field     | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |

+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

| main_id    | int          | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |

| geography  | varchar(30)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |

| table_name | varchar(40)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |

| table_id   | int          | YES  |     | NULL    |                |

+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

mysql> describe table_2;

```
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

| Field       | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |

+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

| table_2_id  | int          | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |

| data_id     | int          | YES  |     | NULL    |                |

| geography   | varchar(30)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |

| source_text | varchar(200) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
```

mysql> select * from table_1 LIMIT 3;

```
+------------+---------------+------------+----------+

|    main_id | geography     | table_name | table_id |

+------------+---------------+------------+----------+

|          1 | united states | fr1_table  |        4 |

|          2 | alabama       | fr1_table  |        5 |

|          3 | alaska        | fr1_table  |        7 |

+------------+---------------+------------+----------+
```

mysql> select * from table_2 LIMIT 3;

```
+------------+---------------+------------+-------------+

| table_2_id | data_id     | geography | source_text    |

+------------+---------------+------------+-------------+

|          1 | 4           | NULL      |'sample text 1' |

|          2 | 5           | NULL      |'sample text 2' |

|          3 | 7           | NULL      |'sample text 3' |

+------------+---------------+------------+-------------+
```

I am trying to insert table_1.geography values into table_2.geography where table_1.table_id = table_2.data_id.

The result would be 
mysql> select * from table_2 LIMIT 3;

```
+------------+---------------+-------------+----------------+

| table_2_id | data_id     | geography     | source_text    |

+------------+---------------+-------------+----------------+

|          1 | 4           | united states |'sample text 1' |

|          2 | 5           | alabama       |'sample text 2' |

|          3 | 7           | alaska        |'sample text 3' |

+------------+---------------+------------+-----------------+
```

There are hundreds of rows so doing it manually is not a feasible solution.
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You join both tables and update the second table

```
UPDATE table_2 t2
LEFT JOIN table_1 t1 ON t2.data_id = t1-table_id
SET t2.geography  = t1.geography
```